# Excel VBA - Deleting Table Rows and Columns From Each Sheet Triggers Run-Time Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that deletes all of the columns (except for 3), all of the rows (except for 1), and clears all contents from all tables in every worksheet that is blue (accent 5, lighter 80%).

The code seems to work just fine until it gets to the final tab (there is only 1 table per tab) and triggers a Run-Time Error 91:

```
Sub ClearTables()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Tab.Color = 16247773 Then
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            With tbl.DataBodyRange
                If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
                    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Delete
                End If
                
                If .Columns.Count > 3 Then
                    .Offset(, 3).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 3).Delete
                End If
                
                .Cells.ClearContents
                
            End With
        Next tbl
    End If
Next sht
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
The error appears at `If .Rows.Count > 1 Then`
[image: Image of Run-Time Error 91 highlighted at If .Rows.Count > Then]

I know I need to set a variable, but I can't seem to figure out how to set to the current table.

Can anyone help explain how I could do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line is the error coming from?  What is different about the table on the last sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams There are 8 sheets: Sheets 1, 4, 5, and 8 had data; Sheets 2, 3, 6, and 7 had no data. The code ran through Sheets 1 - 6 (at least according to the Locals Window while debugging) but then the Run-Time Error 90 would occur at Sheet 7. Thank you for explaining what may have been causing the issue, in your response below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty listobject has no `DataBodyRange` - you can fix those cases by adding a single row to make sure you're not trying to work with a table in that state:

```
'...
'...
For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
    'make sure table is not "empty"
    If tbl.ListRows.Count = 0 Then tbl.ListRows.Add
    'rest of your code is the same as before
    '...
    '...
```